# Can we write junit test cases in Kotlin for the Java classes in an android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit

I am looking forward to migrate a legacy project form Java to Kotlin, which apparently lacks unit test cases.

I wrote test cases in kotlin for a Util class which is written in Java, but when running it I am facing "Tests events were not received". After a lot of searching and trying various SO answers I am still not able to get pass through this.

If i write the same test cases in a Java class then all tests work as expected with a proper report.

Couple of things i wanted to mention:

- There are no build time errors and the build is successful.
- I am using junit:4.13.2
- Android Studio version is Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- The test class is under app/src/test/java
- Tried keeping it under app/src/test/kotlin too but doesn't work
- Tried adding below config under build.gradle but no luck.

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            it.useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
```

Trying all this I started wondering if this is doable or not.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: That is my question since I am unable to make it work. Can you point out what am I missing or how to make it work ?

Comment: No, I don't use Gradle.

Comment: After you get the 'Tests events were not received' message, is there any new output on the 'Build' tab? This might also be a run configuration issue. Does running the Gradle task directly work? Also, please post a screenshot of the Run configuration you're trying to run the tests from. Android Studio might simply be looking for tests in the wrong location, which is often the root cause for 'Tests events were not received' issues

Comment: Please share the name/format of your test class.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me

a) Add following in build.gradle at project root level in

> dependencies

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20"
```

b) Add kotlin plugin in build.gradle at your app level

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

c) Create a test class in your unit test package, make sure that name of class ends with Test. I tried with following name for classes

Named the class ends with Test

status

> Worked

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class Kotlin1KotlinTest {
    @Test
    fun test1() {
        val res = 1 + 1
        assertEquals(2, res)
    }
}
```

Named the class that does not ends with Test

status

> Not working

Got

> Test events were not received

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4
import junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class Kotlin1 {
    @Test
    fun test1() {
        val res = 1 + 1
        assertEquals(2, res)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a simple application with java classes and kotlin tests.

**Java class**

Path: *src/main/java/MyClass.java*

```java
public class MyClass {
    public int addNumbers(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Calculating...");
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**Kotlin test**

Path: *src/test/kotlin/MyClassTest.kt*

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        assertEquals(3, MyClass().addNumbers(1, 2))
    }
}
```

**Gradle file (Kotlin)**

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.21"
    id("java")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Зависимости для JUnit 5
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2")

    // Зависимость для поддержки Kotlin в тестах
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.8.21")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[Project screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAZom.png)

Comment: I am little lost here. I have an existing android project which wasn't using any kotlin at all. When i see the Project screen image you provided i see the "build.gradle.kts" file. How does these configurations work with the usual project and app build.gradle files ?